# Emberjs Many-to-one Unidirectional Relationship

Tags: model, ember.js, relationship, ember-data

Does Emberjs support uni-directional relationships?  Consider that I want to store information about recipes with three models:

- `Ingredient`

  - Always exists.  Gives a `name` and `description`.
  - Nothing "owns" an ingredient, nor should they be duplicated upon new references, or destroyed when references are destroyed.  They just **are**.
- `IngredientAddition`

  - Consists of one `Ingredient` and information when/who to add the ingredient, and quantity
  - Many `IngredientAddition` objects can use the same ingredient.
- `Recipe`

  - Consists of many `IngredientAddition` objects, and ancillary information.

As I understand things, my model looks like the following:

```
App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  desc: DS.attr('string'),
});
App.IngredientAddition = DS.Model.extend({
  how:  DS.attr('string'),
  qty:  DS.attr('string'),
  recipe: DS.belongsTo('App.Recipe'),
});
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
  desc: DS.attr('string'),
  ingredients: DS.hasMany('App.IngredientAddition'),
});
```

However, this does not capture the relationship between `IngredientAddition` and `Ingredient`. `DS.hasMany` does not seem appropriate, since each IngredientAddition has exactly one `Ingredient`.  `DS.belongsTo` is not appropriate, since the `Ingredient` lifecycle is not dictated by the existence (or lack thereof) of an `IngredientAddition`.

How do I capture this information? I've looked at the `ember-data` source, and I can't find any relationship types aside from `hasMany` and `belongsTo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `belongsTo` relationship on `IngredientAddition`.

```
App.IngredientAddition = DS.Model.extend({
  how:  DS.attr('string'),
  qty:  DS.attr('string'),
  ingredient: DS.belongsTo('App.Ingredient'),
  recipe: DS.belongsTo('App.Recipe'),
});
```

This way, `IngredientAddition` has an underlying `ingredient_id` that points to the relevant `Ingredient`. The semantics of an `Ingredient` "owning" an `IngredientAddition` are weird, but this is the way to produce the relationship you have described.

Comment: From looking at how Ember manages the references, it doesn't appear that the `IngredientAddition` object will be updated when `Ingredient` changes.  The bindings look like they're one-way.